# Connecting to HTTPS web services API with node.js v4.2.6?

Tags: json, node.js, web-services, https

I'm looking at connecting to an https web api, I've obtained my token, and my username by receiving an email about it, and there isn't really any sample code to connect to [the webservice](https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/LaborMarketInformation/get-lmi-by-occupation.aspx) using node; however there are examples for Java and C#, and based on those this is what I came up with...

```
/* WEB API: https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/technical-information.aspx?frd=true  */

// UserID: ...
// Token Key: ...==
// Your agreement will expire three years from today on 12/8/2019 and all Web API services will be discontinued,
// unless you renew.

var https = require('https');
var username = '...';
var tokenKey = "...==";

var options = {
  host: 'api.careeronestop.org',
  port: 443,
  path: '/v1/jobsearch/' + username + '/Computer%20Programmer/15904/200/2',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : '' + new Buffer(tokenKey.toString('base64'))
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Unfortunately however, it returns a `401 Unauthorized`, so is there anything that needs added to this to get it working?  Some headers maybe?

Comment: The API access examples (in Java) that I see use a custom header named "Bearer" for the token, not "Authorization" like [this one here](https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/AmericanJobCentersList/list-ajcs-by-location.aspx).  Did you see some doc that suggested you should use "Authorization"?  Also, why are you using a Buffer?  Headers are strings, not binary.  It also shows an "Accept" header for "application/json".

Comment: @jfriend00 Are you talking about this?  `httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer API Token")`

Comment: No, I don't know Java, but what I saw was [this](https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/AmericanJobCentersList/list-ajcs-by-location.aspx): `http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your API Token");`  What doc are you looking at?

Comment: Did uou try just in this way
'Authorization' : '' + tokenKey

Comment: FYI, if you're confused about example what the raw HTTP request should look like, you could use [this form](https://api.careeronestop.org/api-explorer/home/index/AJCFinder_GetOneStopCenter) and then open the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see exactly what request it is sending.

Comment: @DenisLisitskiy yes.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this form](https://api.careeronestop.org/api-explorer/home/index/AJCFinder_GetOneStopCenter) to submit a request and then looked in the Chrome debugger network tab to see exactly what request was sent.

The authorization header is supposed to look like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer 901287340912874309123784
```

You also want this:

```
Accept: application/json
```

So, assuming tokenKey is already a string since it appears to have been sent to you in an email, you can change your code to this:

```
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',  
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenKey
  }
```